# How do I force learning in the new UI when utterances are shown as Not Learned?

Tags: bixby

[image]

I want there to be a way to force these two items to become learned or at least to reveal to me why they are not Not Learned. But I can't figure out what if anything I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this a couple of times where I was "sure" my training was correct, yet I got the "not learned" status

I suggest you check to see if runs properly using the "Aligned NL" feature in the V2 training when you choose Run in the Simulator

If that works, the fix I'm using might work for you.

I found that if I add a vocab to work with my enum, then my training gets learned

Answer (score 0):

When training utterances aren't being learned, odds are that there are conflicting examples that Bixby cannot reconcile.

In this case, I would recommend first attempting to teach Bixby a few "follow" utterances until you can confirm Bixby is able to learn that. Then, attempt a few "unfollow" utterances. If the previously learned "follow" utterances become unlearned, the "follow" and "unfollow" utterances are conflicting.

I would also recommend that you look through the [training documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.best-practices) as it explains the nuance of training Bixby.

Comment: I would like the IDE to give me better than "odds are". ;-) It should be able to say "conflicting examples found".

Comment: This is an excellent feature to request! I would recommend making a post on the feature request forum (https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) which will bring it to the attention of the Product team while also giving other developers a chance to lend their support by upvoting your post.